# XMLHttpRequest asynchronous not working, always returns status 0

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Here's a sample XMLHttpRequest I cobbled together from w3schools

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
  var T="nothing";

  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/plain');  // don't sc
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    alert ("rdystate: " + xmlhttp.readyState);
    alert ("status: "   + xmlhttp.status);
    alert ("Text: "     + xmlhttp.statusText);
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      T = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","SBL_PROBES.htm",true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
//T = xmlhttp.responseText;
alert(T);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Using the XMLHttpRequest object</h2>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">CHange Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

XMLHttpRequest always returns a zero status.

Nothing shows up in Firefox's error console.

If I change the request to synchronous one by changing the line

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","SBL_PROBES.htm",true);
```

to

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","SBL_PROBES.htm",false);
```

and un-comment the line

```
//T = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

The text of the requested file is returned.

The HTM and the file reside in the same directory.  If you try this you will need a file SBL_PROBES.htm there also, it's contents are irrelevant.

I'm using Firefox 3.6.22.

Could this be a cross domain problem?  If so, why does it work as a synchronous request?

Comment: Please confirm that you are definitely running this page from a web server, and not from your local machine's filesystem.  ie, when you visit the test page in your browser you see the url start with http and not file.

Comment: My apologies to all for bothering you with this.  My problem was indeed that I was not running through the server but as a file.  Somehow, I got it through my head that because I had a .htm file I was going through the server.  I accepted evilhead's answer because he had the perseverance to keep asking me about this until it penetrated my thick skull :-)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest Take a look at the "XMLHttpRequests being stopped" section.
It looks like an UNSENT error.

Comment: To elaborate further: The problem has to do with security. See http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/282972/why-am-i-getting-xmlhttprequest.status0: _The XMLHttpRequest object is subjected to the browser’s security “sandbox.” Any resources
requested by the XMLHttpRequest object must reside within the same domain from which the
calling script originated._

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a function inside the if statement. This function is executed when readystate changes to 4.

```
var handleResponse = function (status, response) {
   alert(response)
}
var handleStateChange = function () {
   switch (xmlhttp.readyState) {
      case 0 : // UNINITIALIZED
      case 1 : // LOADING
      case 2 : // LOADED
      case 3 : // INTERACTIVE
      break;
      case 4 : // COMPLETED
      handleResponse(xmlhttp.status, xmlhttp.responseText);
      break;
      default: alert("error");
   }
}
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=handleStateChange;
xmlhttp.open("GET","SBL_PROBES.htm",true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Your old code did a asynchronous call and continued just with the alert Statement. T was empty at this time.

Ok, I'll explain a little bit how this whole thing works:

First we define two callback functions, which we call later in the request, named handleResponse and handleStateChange.

Afterwards we create a Object, which represents the XMLHttpRequest

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
```

This results in an Object as follows (simplyfied):

```
XMLHttpRequest { status=0, readyState=0, multipart=false, onreadystatechange=handleEvent()}
```

With the open(...) function call you set parameters  for the request:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","SBL_PROBES.htm",true);
```

This means, do a asynchronous GET Request to fetch the Page SBL_PROBES.htm
Then the send(...) function is called which fires the request itself.

We registered a callback function for the onreadystatechange, as you can imagine, this is actually an eventHandler. Each time the state changes this function is called. (It is the same as if you register a callback function to an onKeyUp Event in a form, this callback is triggered each time your key goes up :) )

The only case which is of interest for your problem is state 4. Therefor the handleRequest callback function is called only in state 4. At this time you Request has actually a result, and further a status. (Status means your webserver returned a status code 200=ok, 404=not found etc.)

That is not all the magic which is behind the ajax stuff, but should give you a simplified overview, what is actually happening behind the scenes.
It is important that you test this on a webserver, do not use file:// for testing.

If you need more in detail info, just let me know.

Comment: I NEVER see a call on the function where readyState = 4 AND status is non zero.

Comment: One Problem at a time. In handleResponse just do an alert("foo"), is the alert called correctly? Just dont care about the status at this moment. Btw. you can left out "SBL_PROBES.htm". Just put in a "/" and just check if the alert is called.

Comment: Ok.  I took out the check on status, only checking readyState == 4.  The alert in the handleStateChange then shows T with the proper content.  The other alert at the end also went off b4 the one above showing nothing.  So how do I wait for the request to complete?

Comment: I was happy with the synchronous request but wanted to get the status to see if things worked or not.  Can I get status doing a synch request?  Or do I need a asynch request to get status?

Comment: you can do either a synchronous or a asynchronous call. Both support status anyway. But "normally" you use xmlhttp requests with asynchronous calls, because you want that something is happening in the "background" and a function is called when the request finished.

Comment: btw. I hardly suggest you to use a library like jquery for that. It is much easier to handle. I see no point (beneath learning), to implement xmlhttprequests by hand.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3380/discussion-between-evildead-and-mike-d)

Comment: Nothing like the solution picked where the post does not have the solution, but the chat does.

Comment: epascarello:  Well, I decided to reward the guy who answered my comments and had the perseverance to penetrate my psyche.

Answer (score 9):

Status Zero happens for two reasons.

1. You are running off the file protocol.
2. Something is posting back the page when the Ajax request is active.

I believe you are seeing #2 here. SO you need to cancel the button click.

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc(); return false;">CHange Content</button>
```

In your code above that alert(T) will always say *nothing* when the request is asynchronous.

Comment: Makes no difference, status is always zero.

Comment: Are you running this from a server or from your hard drive [aka c:\file.html]? If it is your hardrive you will never see 200.

Comment: #2 was happening, post back was killing the active Ajax request... Good man!

Comment: Wholy cow !! ... #2 !!!  After  days of banging my head to the floor. Thanks !! ... But can somebody please explain me what exactly was happening ?

Comment: @epascarello I would like an explanation for #2 too please. Why would the button be doing anything other than the function specified in onclick?

Comment: @Visualise Because submit buttons submit and anchors navigate the page. But a type button should not submit the form. :) And this question is 6 years old.

Answer (score 3):

Its because async returns before the request returns. Synchronous requests return after the request returns.

Try manipulating your logic in here.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    alert ("rdystate: " + xmlhttp.readyState);
    alert ("status: "   + xmlhttp.status);
    alert ("Text: "     + xmlhttp.statusText);
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      T = xmlhttp.responseText;
      alert(T);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Daniel A. White:  I'm sorry I don't understand, we never get there because xmlhttp.status is always zero.

Comment: Alert is caps, changed to alert. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've battled the problem of not getting a result when using asynchronous XMLHttpRequest open statement. Since this question is the first I found when using google, here is how I solved it:

If you use a button that is inside a form, make sure it is set to type="submit" and onclick="return myFunction()". And in myFunction(), make sure you return false, **not** true! By returning true from the function, you reload the page and the XML object disappears. If you return false, the XML request gets the time it needs to complete and the onreadystatechange function will be run.

Source: [Flask Mailing List](http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2012/6/30/using-ajax-with-flask/#4e04a81a6d9d6c5af151ec7058ae4610)

Answer (score 0):

I have now received the good response to this common problem. The response follow:

This is a very common problem when developing for the web. There's two ways around it.

1. The first is to use JSONP, which our API supports when you add a query parameter ("?callback=foo"). This should get you up and running right away and is great for development, but it isn't secure for production use since users get access to your API key.
2. The second (which is what we use on Forecast, and is the best method for production) is to set up a proxy server on your own domain which can make requests to Forecast on the user's behalf. This sidesteps the browser's same-origin policy, prevents users from accessing your API key (which can be stored server-side), and also allows you to make use of request caching, if desired. (Our favorite web server, NGINX, supports this out of the box and is really easy to configure. If you need some sample configurations, let us know!)