# How to use the result from a API call for another call?

Tags: javascript, json, api, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I hope someone can help me, because i can't get it to work and it's really frustrating.

I have the following code

```
var getJSON = (url, callback) => {


    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

       if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
           callback(xhr.response);
       }
    };
    xhr.send();
};
```

I want to use it to get a json object from the given url but inside the function I want to use the response to get another json object back.

```
var func1 = (url) => {
   getJSON(url, (data) => {
       //Do smth here with the data and then for example
       func2('https://someurl.com/api/somefunction/' + data.smth.age);
   });
}
```

Now the problem is that in `func2` the data will be `null` or `undefinded` and it doesn't work after that.

In addition I have more than 2 functions which try to call `getJSON`.

I hope someone has a solution.

Comment: did u try console.log(data) and console.log(data.smth.age) inside getJSON of func1

Comment: yes in func1 it's still working but when func2 passing the result to the url of func3 it'll be null or undefined

Comment: can u please add func2 and func3 as well

Comment: func2 and func3 is the same as func1 just that the data from func1 gives me smth needed for the url in func2 and so on. Its a nested path.

Comment: just a hunch; create a global variable and assign data to it; then try accessing it inside func2;

Comment: Tried it but didn't work. The problem is, that the xmlhttprequest asynchronous is. The function will be called before the the response is back so that it'll be null.

Comment: `var func1 = (url) => {` is missing the arrow here. but I suppose that this may not be the same in your workspace.

Comment: @JayZheng check out the top answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393484/xmlhttprequest-asynchronous-not-working-always-returns-status-0