# JavaScript: XMLHttpRequest status always returns 0

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to read a file on my server, in the same sub-domain and display its contents. I've seen similar issues here on [XMLHttpRequest asynchronous not working, always returns status 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393484/xmlhttprequest-asynchronous-not-working-always-returns-status-0) except that in my case all files are on my server and within the same sub-domain (the same directory, even) and I didn't want to hijack somebody else's thread.

I have three files on my server:

counter.txt:

```
1234
```

loadfile.js:

```
function loadFile(filePath) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =  this.responseText;
        } else {
            debug = 'readyState=' + this.readyState + '<br />status=' + this.status + '<br />responseText=' + this.responseText;
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = debug;
        }

    };
    xhttp.open("GET", filePath, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

test.html ([url](https://downloads.solydxk.com/.counters/test.html)):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="loadfile.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadFile('counter.txt')">
        <h1>XMLHttpRequest Test</h1>
        <div id='output'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output is always:

```
XMLHttpRequest Test
readyState=4
status=0
responseText=
```

Is there something that I missed?

**[EDIT - 12 July 2018, 20:07]**

```
curl -I https://downloads.solydxk.com/.counters/counter.txt
```

Returns this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 18:04:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 5
Last-Modified: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 12:27:35 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5b474937-5"
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; always
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'none'; font-src 'none'; frame-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; connect-src 'none'; object-src 'none'; media-src 'none'; form-action 'none'; base-uri downloads.solydxk.com www.downloads.solydxk.com
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

---

**[SOLUTION]**

In the Content-Security-Policy part you see that connect-src is set to 'none'. When you're able to change the Apache settings on your server, check that the headers of your domain are configured correctly.

In my case I had to set connect-src to 'self'.

When you're using Plesk to maintain your server:
Websites & Domains > your domain > Apache & nginx settings > Additional headers > Enter custom value:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'none'; font-src 'none'; frame-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; connect-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; media-src 'none'; form-action 'none'; base-uri $host www.$host
```

Comment: Are you "serving" `counter.txt` ? What's the url to access it ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried registering the "load" handler instead of

xhttp.onreadystatechange = your function

xhttp.addEventListener("load", your function);

Comment: Same result. the defined function in addEventListener is never reached.

Answer (score 1):

Check in dev tool :

```
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'none'".
```

Comment: I have that error, but without the 'none' at the end. That surprises me because counter.txt is in the same directory as test.html.

Comment: Ah, that was only in Firefox (61.0.1). In Chromium it is exactly as you stated. Does it have anything to do with https?

Comment: On the server, I've changed the Content-Security-Policy header for connect-src to 'self' and now the script works fine!

Comment: Good job. You should update your question that you fixed it, and how to fix it.

Comment: No, not here. You should update in your question `cause` and `your way`, It may be help somebody.

Comment: I did. Check [Solution] in the OP.